# Mailings Masivos con laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Buenas tarde tengo un problema con el envío de los Emails masivos, estoy trabajando con dos tablas que es "mailings" y "customers", y me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1- La ruta es esto. routes/web.php

```
Route::get('mailings/messages', 'MailingsController@messages')->name('admin.mailing.messages');
```

2- Esto es el modelo app/Mailing.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mailing extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'porcentage', 'name', 'price', 'content', ' avatar', 'valid_month', 'cellphone01', 'cellphone02', 'phone', 'email'
    ];

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
    }


}
```

3- Esto es el modelo app/Customer.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'address', 'phone'
    ];

    public function mailings()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Mailing::class);
    }
}
```

4- Esto es el controlador app/Http/controllers/Admin/CustosmersController.php

```
public function messages(){

    $mailings = Mailing::all();

    Customer::chunk(200, function ($customers){
        foreach ($customers as $customer){
            Mail::send('emails.message', ['customer' => $customer], function ($message) use ($customer){
                $message->from('elvin.analistajr@gmail.com', 'Elvin Mejía Paucar');
                $message->to($customer->email, $customer->name)->subject('Tenemos novedades para ti ' . $customer->name);
            });
        }
    });

    return back()->with('flash', ' Tu mensaje ha sido recibido con éxito', compact('mailings'));

}
```

5- Esto es la vista message.blade.php

```
@foreach($mailings as $mailing)
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <h1 style="margin: 0px; font-size: 48px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; color: #fff;">
                    <strong>{{ $mailing->porcentage }}% de descuento</strong>
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3 style="font-size: 24px; color: #fff; text-align: center; margin: 0; line-height: 11px;">{{ $mailing->name }}</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4 style="text-decoration:line-through; color: #fff; text-align: center; margin: 0;">Antes: {{ $mailing->price }}. 00</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

Agradeceré que puedan ayudarme por favor

Tabla customers

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla mailings

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aqui te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: En concreto una recomendación, el código añádelo con la etiqueta de de código  para que esté en texto y la cualquiera que quiera ayudarte pueda  copiarlo sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es porque estas volviendo a la pagina anterior pero esos datos son pasados a través de variables de session.

En lugar de:

```
return back()->with('flash', ' Tu mensaje ha sido recibido con éxito', compact('mailings'));
```

Deberias retornar la vista y pasarle los datos ahí:

`return view('ruta.a.vista', compact("mailings"))->with('flash', 'Tu mensaje ha sido recibido con éxito')`;

Comment: amigo muchas gracias

Comment: De nada @ElvinMejía,me alegro que te haya servido la respuesta,deberías marcala como correcta para que pueda ayudar a futuras personas con el mismo problema.
Saludos.